# How can I simplify the code to pass props to child components?

Tags: reactjs

I want to simplify my code to pass all my props to child components.

```
export default function HomePage() {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);
  const [totalResults, setTotal] = useState([]);
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState([]);
  const [tag, setTag] = useState([]);
  const [hideDelFilters, setHideDelFilters] = useState(true);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(12);

 {...}

  return (
    <section className="homePage">
      <Header />
      <Breadcrumb />
      <div className="body">
        <FiltersList hideDelFilters={hideDelFilters} navigate={navigate} results={results} filters={filters} search={search} getResults={getResults} tag={tag} />
        <div className="content col">
          <SearchBar navigate={navigate} search={search} setSearch={setSearch} />
          <ResultsList page={page} setPage={setPage}  search={search} getResults={getResults} tag={tag} pageSize={pageSize} results={results} totalResults={totalResults} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

I tried to use {... props} but it doesn't work.

Any advice?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create an object for all the states

like

```
export default function HomePage() {
   const navigate = useNavigate();
   const [globalState, setGlobalState] = useState({
      search:"",
      results:[],
      totalResults:[],
      filters:[],
      tag:[],
      hideDelFilters:true,
      page:1,
      pageSize:12
  })

  ...

  return (
    <section className="homePage">
      <Header />
      <Breadcrumb />
      <div className="body">
        <FiltersList navigate={navigate} globalState={globalState} setGlobalState={setGlobalState} />
        <div className="content col">
          <SearchBar navigate={navigate} globalState={globalState} setGlobalState={setGlobalState} />
          <ResultsList globalState={globalState} setGlobalState={setGlobalState} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
}
```

And then access them in child component like

`props.globalState.page` and `props.setGlobalState.page`

Comment: Although I believe it is a viable solution, be cautious when manipulating arrays in states as it won't trigger `useEffect`s.